# reading the output of readelf -wi, why do some local variables have a DW_AT_location value, but others do not?

Tags: c, dwarf, readelf

I am running readelf -wi file.elf, and looking at the output. I am looking at some of the debug info for local variables, I can find all the variables listed (they all have DW_AT_name), but some do not have

```
DW_AT_location : stuff
```

why?

Is there a way to get the location of local variables that don't have this line? No I cannot recompile the code, I have the source, but cannot edit it or recompile it with more gcc flags or anything. I have the dissasembly and elf file (obviously).

Comment: Looks like DW_AT_ is related to the Abbreviation Table for [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF), from the manual at https://gcc-renesas.com/gnu-tools-manuals/gnu-sh-user-manual/

Comment: I looked, and didn't find anything that popped out that explained why some local variables have a location specified and others do not, got any insights?